# Get x value with given probability

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, gaussian

An energy-saving lamp lights up an average of 10,000 hours before it fails, with a standard deviation of 800 hours.

What is the minimum burn time achieved by 90% of the lamps? A Gaussian distribution is given.

I used this formula:

$z = \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma }$

Transformed it to:

$x = \mu + z \cdot \sigma$

Which is:

$x = 10000 + 1.2815 \cdot 800 = 11.0250$

That is not the right result, what do I wrong?

Addendum

After trying a little bit around I came to the conclusion that the following equation transformed leads to the right result:

$z = \frac{x + \mu}{\sigma }$

Transformed:

$x = \mu - z \cdot \sigma$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your z score had the wrong sign. Since it wants the minimum burn time achieved by 90% of the lamps you are looking for the 10th percentile, not 90th percentile. So -1.25 standard deviations below the mean.

Comment: Nice catch (+1), In R statistical software quantile .1 of $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=10000, \sigma=300)$ can be found by code `qnorm(.1, 10000, 300)`, which returns  $9615.535$ or (to about the nearest whole number of hours) by standardizing and using printed normal CDF tables.

Comment: @BruceET — thanks — quick question — standard dev. is 800 in OP — we’re you using 300 as an example?

Comment: Yes. Should have noted that: Thanks. // Variant to avoid providing exact numerical answer to what seems a possible hwk problem.